# Convert a Python application which uses PyQt5 to WebAssembly

Tags: pyqt5, webassembly

Is there any way to convert a python application which uses PyQt5 to WebAssembly? Or I must use the html components to render UI?

Comment: To my knowledge the conversion cannot be done.

Comment: What do you mean? Have the GUI automatically converted from the desktop framework to a Web application? No.

Comment: Yes, I have inspired this solution from this article https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/wasm.html

Comment: @chatzich Qt WASM compiles the application to bytecode but there is no tool that does the same with PyQt5.

Comment: I have the same question and have the feeling things may be evolving in forthcoming months. But for the moment, I didn't find any way to tackle this.

Comment: This should be possible https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbB3QEwWMlA&ab_channel=Fireship